# PIC24FJ1024GB610 MLA USB Device Lite USB stack stops working when multiple endpoints are enabled

Tags: usb, pic

I'm using a PIC24FJ1024GB610 and have configured the "MLA USB Device Lite [USB Framework Lite]" using the Microchip Code Configurator utility. The Microchip Lightweight USB Stack settings are: vendor (not CDC), USB tasks polling, Transceiver Option Internal. On the host side, I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and using libusb.

When I just enable endpoint 1:
`USBEnableEndpoint(USB_EP1, USB_IN_ENABLED|USB_OUT_ENABLED|USB_HANDSHAKE_ENABLED|USB_DISALLOW_SETUP);`

the device enumerates fine and I am able to transfer data to/from the host. Here's the output of `lsusb -v -d` (when just EP1 is configured as above):

```
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x04d8 Microchip Technology, Inc.
  idProduct          0x000a CDC RS-232 Emulation Demo
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 Microchip Technology Inc.
  iProduct                2 Product Name
  iSerial                 3 ABCDE
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

However, as soon as I enable a second endpoint (e.g. endpoint 2, but also tried with endpoint 3), the additional endpoints do not appear in the output of lsusb, the iManufacturer, iVendor and iSerial fields all show "(error)", and I can't transfer data to/from the device (on any endpoint, even EP1 stops working):

```
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x04d8 Microchip Technology, Inc.
  idProduct          0x000a CDC RS-232 Emulation Demo
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 (error)
  iProduct                2 (error)
  iSerial                 3 (error)
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Status:     0xcef0
  (Bus Powered)
  Debug Mode
```

To enable the second endpoint, I am simply (and only) adding the following line of code below the line that enables the first endpoint:

`USBEnableEndpoint(USB_EP2, USB_IN_ENABLED|USB_OUT_ENABLED|USB_HANDSHAKE_ENABLED|USB_DISALLOW_SETUP);`

Both of these lines are inside a function (`initialiseUsb`) that is called in the `onUsbConfiguredEvent` callback and the `onUsbResumeEvent` callback.

Is it possible to get the device to enumerate correctly with multiple endpoints enabled, and is it possible to transfer data when multiple endpoints are enabled, using this USB stack? It's strange that enumeration isn't working, since I thought the `onUsbConfiguredEvent` callback was only called after enumeration is complete.

I'm using the USB-C connector on the Explorer 16/32 board, and have tried with several USB cables.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue with USB Lite, on a PIC18F45K50. I'm working on it right now. If you still have this question, I'll be happy to post again when I figure it out. (Or, have you solved it?)

Comment: I was unable to find a solution and would still be very interested. I was force to work around the issue, just using a single endpoint. Please do post an update when you figure it out!